# Javascript lights out (css manipulation), like in YouTube

Tags: javascript, css

How do I use javascript to black out all content except a single html element?

This is Chrome-specific app so CSS3 can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one `<div>` with `position: fixed;` that covers the page, with something like `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);`, then simply place the element you wish to show on top of that.

Comment: Just give the overlay div a z-index higher than your other stuff, and the content element a higher index than that one. :)

#overlay { z-index: 100; } #dialog { z-index: 110; }

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through all the elements of a document and set their background color to black, except the one with a certain ID.

You don't need CSS3 for this at all.

Comment: I can set the back and foreground color to black but what about images, other content?